# How do I fix the module not found error in django

Tags: python, django, miniconda, modulenotfounderror

I created a django project which has 2 apps: **Aceit** and **api**, I am getting a `module not found` error when trying to make migrations or do anything that requires the `manage.py` file.

I am using a virtual environment that uses python 3.10 it is worth noting that I had another project called AceIt(with a capital i as opposed to the one I have now), which I deleted. I am not sure if deleting it is causing these problems but just thought to mention it.

file directory structure:

[image]

stack trace after calling `python manage.py makemigrations`:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\mosta\Desktop\Desktop\Mostafa Azouz\Queen mary\Ace-It!\Code\Backend\api\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\mosta\Desktop\Desktop\Mostafa Azouz\Queen mary\Ace-It!\Code\Backend\api\manage.py", line 18, in main
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:\Users\mosta\miniconda3\envs\Aceit\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\Users\mosta\miniconda3\envs\Aceit\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 416, in execute
        django.setup()
      File "C:\Users\mosta\miniconda3\envs\Aceit\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "C:\Users\mosta\miniconda3\envs\Aceit\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
        app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
      File "C:\Users\mosta\miniconda3\envs\Aceit\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 193, in create
        import_module(entry)
      File "C:\Users\mosta\miniconda3\envs\Aceit\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Aceitdjango'
```

Above I have provided my file directory structure and stack trace of the error, if there is anything else I need to provide let me know.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are referring to a module named `Aceitdjango`, which does not exist.  I'm guessing it's in your `settings.py` file, in the `INSTALLED_APPS` section.